# Reversing enumerable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I'm trying to reverse Enumerable (like Array) without using `reverse` method, but using `reverse_each` iterator.

I hoped, that following code is enough:

```
p [1,2,3].reverse_each {|v| v }
```

however the block doesn't return array in reversed orded. Of course I could write

```
[1,2,3].reverse_each {|v| p v }
```

but I'd like to collect items in the first way. What is the source if this behaviour and how should I write my expression to fulfill requirement?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From 1.8.7, `Enumerable#each_*` methods [return an enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each) when no block is provided, so those originally imperative methods can now be used in pure expressions.

So, if you want to collect items, use `Enumerable#map` on that enumerator:

```
reversed_values = [1, 2, 3].reverse_each.map { |x| 2*x }
#=> [6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another method would be `[1, 2, 3].reverse_each.to_a`

Answer (score -1):

(1..3).reverse_each {|v| p v }

produces:

1 2 3

It Builds a temporary array and traverses that array in reverse order, but do not return the reverse copy of the transformed collection

If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

But map method of ruby

Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.

p [1,2,3].reverse_each.map {|v| v }

reverse_each - will act as an iterator

map - will form a new set of collection